# How to register if a box2d body is clicked in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, geometry, box2d, mouse-position

I'm creating a game with Heroes of Might and Magic like combat in libgdx.

I have a main character on hexagonal ground tiles, all of which are set up as sprites and have a box2d body.

I would like to change the texture of a ground tile's sprite if the box2d body is clicked.

Is there an easy way of telling if a box2d body is clicked by the mouse?

I am polling for input now, but I could try to familiarise myself with `InputProcessor` if it's needed.

Comment: Are you use `Actor` and `Stage` classes?

Comment: @Sergey I was just using Sprites and Screens, but after some googling I realized that I should be using Scene2d and I'm in the process of refactoring my whole project at the moment.

Comment: After refactoring which models you want to use? )

Comment: At the moment I'm using a simple ApplicationAdapter and I'm setting intractable objects and sprites up as Actors. I need to figure out how to setbounds that aren't rectangular though... I'll post this as another question!

Answer (score 1):

To check if the body is clicked:

1. Check when the mouse is clicked and get its position.
2. Get the rectangle of the body and compare it to the mouse position.
3. If the body's rectangle contains the mouse position, the mouse has clicked the body.